# Ghost images (composite images) in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth, imagery

I notice that Google Earth images often have ghost cars or ghost boats. For example:

[image]

So, obviously multiple images from different times are being combined. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

Through my studies I've worked quite a bit with areal photography as well as satellite images. This phenomenon is, if I'm not mistaken, due to two images covering parts of the same area overlapping creating "ghosts".

Since these images were likely taken within seconds of each other, it is likely that the items in the image are still there but if these non-static and are moving, such as boats, it may be that they will appear at two places at the same time.

Comment: correct this is showing the movement of objects with overlaps in the images in a short space of time.

Answer (score 1):

Most "ghost" vehicles in Google Earth and Maps are in areas where multiple images have been stitched together to create the final image layer. These are most common in places where Google has 3D imagery, which is usually acquired from aircraft which take photos of each place from multiple angles. The software then reconstructs both the 3D terrain and a composite imagery layer, and it attempts to remove non-permanent objects like cars, if there is enough data available to fill in the gaps. This process isn't perfect, resulting in the ghosts you see.

For an overview of Google's imaging processes, check out this Nat & Friends video on YouTube: [Google Earth’s Incredible 3D Imagery, Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suo_aUTUpps)